# .Net useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy not working in IIS 7.5

Tags: .net, web-config, iis-7.5

I have a .Net 4.0 application that references third party DLLs, which apparently do not support 4.0. Using useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true" in the config file makes it work when running locally, but not when running on our server in IIS 7.5.

The third party software is from http://crystal-decisions-inc.software.informer.com/, DLL's:

- CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine
- CrystalDecisions.ReportSource
- CrystalDecisions.Shared

Both local machine and web server have installed the same Crystal Reports runtime, CRRuntime_32bit_13_0_5.msi.

My local application is running using a test project, which is a Windows Forms Application. In the app.config, it works when this is included:

```
<configuration>
  ...
  <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true" >
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

When not included, local code causes this exception:

> "Could not load file or assembly 'C:\Program Files (x86)\SAP BusinessObjects\Crystal Reports for .NET Framework 4.0\Common\SAP BusinessObjects Enterprise XI 4.0\win32_x86\dotnet1\crdb_adoplus.dll' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified."

When I add the same <startup> tag to the web.config for the web site, it does not seem to make any difference whether it is present or not. When that line of code gets hit, the code just dies; it does not throw any managed exception.

Googled for help, and all the pages basically state that adding the config settings fixed it for them, usually citing this or a slight variant:

```
<startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
  <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
</startup>
```

But this did not work for my application. Since I cannot get an actual error from the web application, I am at a loss where to go next, help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Since nobody has answered yet, I'll just throw in my five cents.

useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy allows the inclusion of pre .NET 2.0 "weirdness" (usually involving mixed assemblies). But it does so at the expense of side-by-side execution.

I think that you haven't found the correct place for the entry. Don't confuse the Web.Config for the App.Config file. Web.Config serves another, completely different, purpose. I assume you need to find the App.Config file of the executable.

(Wether or not IIS will respond favorably to this setting, I have no idea.)

Comment: I now think that is the key, that it is the app config not web.config; waiting to mark as answer until we actually get this working. I think it may actually be the aspnet.config file...

Comment: Or the app.config of executable of IIS. Come to think of it, you may find the correct configuration file using this: AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ConfigurationFile